# UK Standard Visitor visa refused (V3.6(b), deception on prior convictions, 10 year ban), can I reapply immediately?

Tags: visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, visa-bans

I'm a US permanent resident (30+ years) and applied for a UK visitor visa. There was a question concerning whether I had ever been "convicted" of a crime. I plead guilty to a crime in 1997 (white collar) and adjudication was withheld so I answered "no". My visa was denied because I answered NO and they saw my record when they ran my prints (I traveled without a problem to the UK in 2000).

[image: Refusal letter]

Should I reapply and explain, or wait a while, or forget about it because they'll never approve it?

Comment: Even if adjudication was withheld, did the court find you guilty and sentence you for the crime? That is likely enough to fulfil the UK legal definition of a conviction, although your local legal definitions (Florida?) are different.

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't attract a ban. Anyway, depending upon the crime, they may have now recorded you as an illegal entrant in 2000 making matters worse.  Based upon what you wrote, it's a duplicate. If you want to scan, redact, and upload your refusal notice into a NEW question, you can get some useful answers (given that it's not a duplicate also).

Comment: You can apply immediately. Your real question should be whether they will accept your explanation that you answered "no" because of a misunderstanding of the question, and possibly whether your record of itself will result in the rejection of your application. The best way to find out is just to apply again.

Comment: I'm really surprised that you haven't naturalized.

Comment: @MichaelHampton there are lots of reasons people don't naturalize.  It costs a fair amount. There's an article in the NY Times just now about Mexicans who were motivated to pay the fee and take the oath so they could have the pleasure of voting against Donald Trump.  Voting seems to be the main reason to do it for most people. Other reasons to stay an LPR include not wanting to have to give up the original citizenship, which many countries require, emotional reasons, and inertia in the face of bureaucracy.

Comment: Thank you for all the good comments. @GayotFow the redacted decision was as follows: On question 36 of your UK visa app you are asked "Have you ever been convicted..." you stated no. Information available to us based on your biometric results demonstrate you were convicted in 1997. You have not declared this material fact on your UK visa application. As a result, I am satisfied you have made a false statement on your Uk visa app in order to facilitate entry."

Comment: @MichaelHampton Unfortunately a white collar fraud conviction (medical billing fraud) where the loss to the victim is more than $10k (victim was the State of FL) is an aggravated felony for immigration purposes and keeps you from being a citizen for life.

Comment: @user40983 please scan and upload the full refusal notice; what you wrote does not have the "legal" reasons for your refusal so it's incomplete, also... remember that comments are frequently swept and cleaned by the moderators so the full refusal notice needs to be in the body of your question, many thanks

Comment: @GayotFow the update shows that the OP does indeed have a ban, making this not a duplicate - there is no point in reapplying until 23/02/2026

Comment: @CMaster, thanks for the ping; I will reopen this right now. You can give an answer to the OP straight-away, thanks again  note also he is now an illegal entrant from 2000 for deception by silence per the 1998 Act

Comment: @GayotFow I don't believe in 2000 there was such a question in the visa application, I honestly don't remember even doing an app at that time. There is no such question, for example, in the Shengen Visa app which I routinely fill out and have never been denied. This is the first time that I've had a visa denied.

Comment: @user40983, there isn't a question explicitly on the application. You become an illegal entrant when you use deception by silence and do not disclose material information. You did that in 2000.  They will have already recorded it during your application.  Also, in your application, you also did not check the box about good character, and you will not be back in the UK for a long, long time. 10 years is just the start.

Answer (score 6):

Accordng to the letter your have received, you can reapply whenever you like, but you will be refused for at least the next ten years - 23/02/2026 is the date that the automatic refusal ceases to ocur, according to your above letter.

You can find the immigration rules [on the offical UK government website here](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules). The relevant sections say that (emphasis mine):

> V 3.7 An applicant **will** be refused:
>
> - (a) if the applicant previously breached UK immigration laws as described at V 3.9; and
> - (b) if the applicant is outside the UK, the application is made within the relevant re-entry ban time period in V 3.10 (which time period is relevant will depend on the manner in which the applicant left the UK).

And

> V 3.9 An applicant, when aged 18 years or over, breached the UK’s immigration laws:
>
> - (d) if deception was used in relation to an application or documents used in support of an application (whether successful or not).

V3.10 (f) states that the ban for deception in an application lasts 10 years.

Note the use of the term will - there's no discretion here given to the person assessing your application, they are required to refuse you on the basis of this refusal.

If you feel you have been treated unfairly, and that you have a case to make that this was all an innocent misunderstanding and can be put right, and you really want to visit the UK, you could look into hiring a UK-based immigration lawyer. They will be able to tell you if there is any chance of you being reconsidered or not, but it will cost you a considerable amount of money.